# How to search in ngFor results?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a JSON object and I need to iterate it and include a search functionality that displays the key and values searched in that key.

I achieved this Using a pipe and by looping over keys and its values.

**COMPONENT.HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "Search"[(ngModel)] = "query" id = "listSearch"  #search >

      <ul>
      <li * ngFor="let key of objectKey()" >
        <span>{{ key }}</span>
          < table >
          <tr * ngFor="let item of (testData[key] | LockFilter:'appName': search.value) as result" >
            <td>{{ item.appName }}</td>
              < /tr>
              < /table>
              < /li>
              < /ul>
```

**COMPONENT.TS:**

```
testData = {
  "MyCat1": [
    {
      "appName": "Myapp1",
      "appCatName": "MyCat1"
    },
    {
      "appName": "Myapp2",
      "appCatName": "MyCat1"
    }
  ],
  "MyCat2": [
    {
      "appName": "Myapp3",
      "appCatName": "MyCat2"
    },
    {
      "appName": "Myapp4",
      "appCatName": "MyCat2"
    }
  ]
}
objectKey() {
  return Object.keys(this.testData);
}
```

**PIPE.TS:**

```
transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {

  if (!items) return [];
  if (!value) return items;

  return items.filter(str => {
    return str[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
  });

}
```

> Expected Results BEFORE SEARCH: 
>   MyCat1: 
>   Myapp1 
>   Myapp2
>
> MyCat2:
>   Myapp3
>   Myapp4
>
> AFTER SEARCH: (search string '1') 
>   MyCat1: 
>   Myapp1

[Current Output Image [image: Current Output Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZslk.png)

Comment: This seems like a reasonable use of a pipe to me. What is your question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want the keys to be removed from UI if no values are found under it when searched for a specific string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="search" />
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let key of objectKey()" [hidden]="!(testData[key] | LockFilter:'appName': search).length">
        <span>{{ key }}</span>
        <table>
            <tr *ngFor="let  item of (testData[key] | LockFilter:'appName': search) as result">
                <td> {{ item.appName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayucpz)

Comment: This works very well, but can you suggest a more customized way??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  // check if exists and will return the keys
  objectKey(value) {
    return Object.entries(this.testData)
      .filter(data=> (data[1].filter(item=> item[value].includes(this.search)).length))
      .map([KEY, VAL] => KEY)
  }
```

in HTML (the same code)

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let key of objectKey('appName')"  >
      <span   >{{ key }}</span>
        <table>
          <tr *ngFor="let  item of (testData[key] | LockFilter:'appName': search) as result" >
              <td >   {{ item.appName }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayucpz)